# How can I find the smallest of 3 integers in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

As a beginner in Haskell I am trying to write a code to find the smallest number out of 3 integers. This is what I have so far. Can anyone push me in the right direction?

```
smallest :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
smallest a b c = min a b c
```

Comment: If that _was_ a possible implementation, then there would be no need to define `smallest` at all – you could just just `min` right in place where you need to find the smallest number.

Answer (score 10):

`min` function accepts two arguments, that's why your code doesn't compile. However, your can call `min` twice:

```
smallest :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
smallest a b c = min a (min b c)
```

If you are unsatisfied with calling it twice and want a more concise solution, you can use `minimum` function. It accepts a list and returns its minimum value:

```
smallest :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
smallest a b c = minimum [a, b, c]
```

Comment: The infix version, ``smallest a b c = a `min` b `min` c``, also looks pretty nice.

Answer (score 5):

@Zheka's code works fine for three numbers, and if you ever needed more, it's enough to notice that `min a (min b c)` looks just like a fold:

```
smallest a b c = foldl1 min [a, b, c]
```

Comment: `min a (min b c)` actually corresponds to `foldr1 min [a,b,c]`. With the left fold `foldl1`, it's `min (min a b) c`, which gives of course the same result.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I have to admit I didn't really think about that since it's pretty obvious that both the left and right fold can be used here, but you're obviously right.

Answer (score 0):

Pointfree style:

```
smallest :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
smallest = (min .) . min
```